# Array to hash of key value pairs in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From a model that returns all the values from a table, how would I convert that to a hash of name value pairs

```
{column_value => column_value}
```

e.g.

```
[{:id => 1, :name => 'first'}, {:id => 2, :name => 'second'}, {:id => 3, :name => 'third'}]
```

to (specifying :id and :name)

```
{'first' => 1, 'second' => 2, 'third' => 3}
```

Comment: I wonder if it could be done in one line...

Comment: @Christopher: Yes, it can be done with a one-liner, too.  I updated my answer with a one-liner solution as an alternative.

Comment: You sure can; see my answer using `inject`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following approach is reasonably compact, yet still readable:

```
def join_rows(rows, key_column, value_column)
  result = {}
  rows.each { |row| result[row[key_column]] = row[value_column] }
  result
end
```

Usage:

```
>> rows = [{:id => 1, :name => 'first'}, {:id => 2, :name => 'second'}, {:id => 3, :name => 'third'}]
>> join_rows(rows, :name, :id)
=> {"third"=>3, "second"=>2, "first"=>1}
```

Or, if you want a one-liner:

```
>> rows.inject({}) { |result, row| result.update(row[:name] => row[:id]) }
=> {"third"=>3, "second"=>2, "first"=>1}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in one line with `inject`:

```
a = [{:id => 1, :name => 'first'}, {:id => 2, :name => 'second'}, {:id => 3, :name => 'third'}]
a.inject({}) { |sum, h| sum.merge({ h[:name] => h[:id]}) }
# => {"third" => 3, "second" => 2, "first" => 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
o = Hash.new
a = [{:id => 1, :name => 'first'}, {:id => 2, :name => 'second'}, {:id => 3, :name => 'third'}]
a.each {|h| o[h[:name]] = h[:id] }

puts o #{'third' => 3, 'second' => 2, 'first' => 1}
```